# Load TIFF images with Keras ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tiff

I'm trying to launch a multi-class training with U-Net in Keras/Tensorflow in Python 3.7. I only have experience performing binary training with .jpg images (images with values ​​in the ranges [0,255]) in grayscale (1 channel), which I loaded with the ImageDataGenerator class.

In this case, **I need to load 1-channel .tif images with values ​​ranging from -1000 to 7000**. As far as I can tell, ImageDataGenerator loads the images in [0,255], which causes me to lose a lot of information. Is there any way to load those images with the original values ​​using ImageDataGenerator? I know the Pillow library loads them properly, but I have a lot of data and I needed to load that efficiently.

Assuming I have the images in `/full/path/to/my/dir/images` and the masks in `/full/path/to/my/dir/masks`, the code I'm using to load the images and the masks are as follows:

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_image_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/full/path/to/my/dir",
    classes="images",
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    target_size=(400, 400),
    class_mode=None,
    seed=100,
    shuffle=True,
)
train_mask_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    "/full/path/to/my/dir",
    classes="masks",
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode="grayscale",
    target_size=(400, 400),
    class_mode=None,
    seed=100,
    shuffle=True,
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this? https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/experimental/image/decode_tiff

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That feature is not what I need as the input is an encoded image and would return the data as uint8, something I am trying to avoid so as not to lose information.

Answer (score 1):

In the ImageDataGenerator there is a preprocessor function that you can define. It processes each image and returns the result. Note the processed image must have the same shape as the input image but you can manipulate the pixel values

Comment: According to the documentation " The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape." Thus, you cannot load tiff file here, it's only preprocessing an image which is already a NumPy array.